# C# takes more time to do first execution

Tags: c#, performance, execution-time

I have noticed an unusual thing with my C# app. The first time I execute some code takes a lot longer than subsequent executions. Can anyone explain to me why this is?

It is even visible with my simple test app below where I get an initial output of around 13 and subsequent outputs of around 3.

```
Stopwatch sw;
int count = 0;
private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    RunTest();
}

private void RunTest()
{
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        count++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first execution includes the time that the Just In Time (JIT) compiler spends converting the code from Microsoft's Intermediary Language (MSIL) into the native executable machine code of whatever machine you're running the code on.

All subsequent calls are re-using that already compiled code.

Comment: Bravo. There's also initial memory allocation to consider, and in more complex examples there's disk/memory buffering, network connection and authentication, results caching etc etc that can make a more real-world algorithm perform more slowly on the initial run for reasons not always apparent.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer. Is there any way to reduce this time?

Comment: I'm not so sure about this... JIT is done *by method*, and he starts measuring time *inside* `RunTest`, which means the `RunTest` method is already JITted at this point. And all other methods he uses (`Console.WriteLine` etc) are NGen'd and in the GAC, so they don't take JIT time at all. I believe he just (micro-)benchmarked this wrong (debug mode or so).

Comment: @user2424495 Run the code before you actually need to in order to pre-load your cache with data you expect to need soon.  Many applications do this.  (Any time you see a "Loading" screen, that's typically what's happening.)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski You've got warm up time for every method that this method calls, i.e. `Stopwatch.StartNew`, `Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks`, and `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: @Servy all these methods are passed through NGen, so you don't need to JIT them. .NET apps would be horribly slow if that was the case.

Comment: @user2424495 You can reduce startup time in general by using [NGEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163610.aspx) on your own code. For WIndows Store Apps, you can use [.NET Native](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/02/announcing-net-native-preview.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

My comments are late but hope they might help someone.

If you clear up the memory and then run the program again,  you will not see the savings you see on subsequent runs.

Here is an example.

I had written a small program that traverses through all the folders on a drive and calculates the total size taken up by the image files. On subsequent runs the program ran much faster as compared to the first run. However there is more to it than the JIT think discussed above.

.Net seems to store an execution plan during the first run and uses it for optimizing subsequent runs. So when I change the folder to e:\work from d:\work, it takes nearly the same time it took for the first run (note - changes to the path are made in config file so no recompiling was required and d:\work is similar in size to e:\work). When the path was changed back to d:\work, .Net executed it in lesser time.